# Plotting multiple lines in ggplot, x-axis repeated

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a chart with multiple lines using ggplot in R. This should be fairly straightforward, however I can't seem to be successful.

My data frame is as follows:

```
> head(PPP)
        date     P       pp     HP
1 28.07.2011 38.88 38.88000 40.824
2 29.07.2011 39.14 39.14000 40.824
3 01.08.2011 38.29 38.83005 40.824
4 02.08.2011 39.07 39.07480 40.824
5 03.08.2011 40.75 39.71282 40.824
6 04.08.2011 38.40 38.94552 40.824
```

I then melt this data using the melt() function of the package "reshape2":

```
> meltPPP<-melt(PPP,id="date")
```

The results looks as follows (to be noted, the "date" column contains now repetitions of values):

```
> head(meltPPP)
        date variable value
1 28.07.2011        P 38.88
2 29.07.2011        P 39.14
3 01.08.2011        P 38.29
4 02.08.2011        P 39.07
5 03.08.2011        P 40.75
6 04.08.2011        P 38.40
```

My goal is to have on the x-axis the values for "date" and on the y-axis of the chart 3 lines: "P","pp", and "HP". I then use the following code to try to plot the chart:

```
> h<-ggplot(meltPPP,aes(date,value,group=variable,colour=variable))
> h+geom_line()
```

However, it seems that R doesn't understand that the values in "date" are not to be repeated. The result is:

[image]

It seems to me that the same chart is repeated and squeezed over and over again. This is probably due to the fact that R doesn't understand that the "date" values are unique.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the `lubridate` package to convert the dates or in base R, you can use `as.POSIXct` to convert to a type that should work.  For example, you could convert a date like this `as.POSIXct('2016-04-04 12:34:56')` or using `lubridate` like this `library(lubridate)` and `ymd_hms('2016-04-04 12:34:56')`.

Comment: Note, your dates are in a different format, when using `lubridate` you may need to use the `dmy` function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have done so far, you could do something like the following, using `lubridate` and `dplyr`. If this is not exactly what you want, it should get you close.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

PPP <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE, text = 'date     P       pp     HP
28.07.2011 38.88 38.88000 40.824
29.07.2011 39.14 39.14000 40.824
01.08.2011 38.29 38.83005 40.824
02.08.2011 39.07 39.07480 40.824
03.08.2011 40.75 39.71282 40.824
04.08.2011 38.40 38.94552 40.824
')

PPP <- PPP %>% mutate(date = dmy(date))
meltPPP<-melt(PPP,id="date")
h <- ggplot(meltPPP,aes(date,value,group=variable,colour=variable)) +
     geom_line()
h
```

[image]